# router.navigate doesn't work if error occurs during ng lifecycle hooks

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an `ErrorHandler` that I use to log all exceptions & then redirect user to generic error page. The problem is that this does work only if the exception that is handled occured outside of any [lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) (or constructor). method. Consider the following example with `ngOnInit`:

```
class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

  handleError(error) {
    // log error

    var router = this.injector.get(Router);

     router.navigate['/error'];
  }
}
```

The error handler is called correctly. However, the router.navigate works only when exception occured after initialization of component.

Doesn't work:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  template: ''
})
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit{
    ngOnInit() {
    throw Error(`Boom!`);
  }
}
```

Works as expected:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  template: `<button (click)="handleClick()">click me</button>`
})
export class SampleComponent{
      private handleClick(): void{
        throw Error(`Boom!`);
    }
}
```

Am I missing something or how can I make this work? I suppose I can use `windows.location.href`, but that will reload the page which is something I would rather avoid.

Comment: I have the same issue, but throwing errors in constuctor(){} navigates as expected.

Answer (score 1):

After some time I feel like the best solution is indeed to 'redirect' application to an error page using `'window.location.href'`. You never know what kind of error you end up with & in some cases the application could become totally broken.

Answer (score 0):

Injection in **MyErrorHandler** isn't correct.

Change `{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler }` in **app.module.ts** on

```
{
  provide: ExceptionHandler,
    useFactory: (router) => {
      return new MyErrorHandler(router);
    },
  deps: [Router]
}
```

So now you have properly injected router.

Comment: hey, thanks for the suggestion. Tried this, but it gives cyclic dependency error for ApplicationRef. It is maybe worth noting that the services I instantiate in ErrorHandler do work - I can successfully call my services and do all kind of things - except routing.